# Wordpress: Cannot login in after upgrade - redirects to blank page

Tags: wordpress

I updated a clients Wordpress to 3.5.2 and now cannot login via wp-admin.

The login form appears but once I hit the Log In button I am just redirect to a blank page with a single `.` on it. Same happens if I enter the wrong password.

I have checked out the [Login Trouble Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble) and tried replacing the wp-login.php file and disabling all plugins to no affect. I get the same issue occuring.

Front of the site seems fine.

What appreas in debug:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/stretton/public_html/fo/wp-content/themes/freya/lib/widgets/banners-125.php:13) in /home/stretton/public_html/fo/wp-login.php on line 369

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/stretton/public_html/fo/wp-content/themes/freya/lib/widgets/banners-125.php:13) in /home/stretton/public_html/fo/wp-login.php on line 381
```

EDIT: I have also tried:

- Renaming my theme to defualt it to the twentytwelve theme
- Renaming the plugins directory
- Removing the widgets directory
- Replacing WP-Admin with from a fresh download

No luck with these either

Comment: Can you enable the debug mode? Just change your wp-config.php line `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` And see if it shows any error.

Comment: @Melvin thanks - a lot comes up in debug, but the two messages I have entered above seem to be concerned with wp-login.php

Comment: @Melvin actually all the errors seem to be focused around the widgets folder. Im not sure what this could mean

Comment: Glad to be of help. It's been narrowed down.. Can you show the contents of banners-125.php ? You can paste them [here](http://paste.laravel.com), save, and paste the link here.. And I'll see if I can help. :)

Comment: @Melvin yep I have done that! thanks! Link is: http://www.strettonelectorateoffice.com.au/fo/wp-login.php you dont need the username and password as the same thing occurs on the error page as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the active theme and force a revert to twentytwelve. Theme issues can still sometimes cause admin errors. But once the theme reverts, you should be able to get into admin, even if the front end is white-screened.

To figure out what's causing the white screen on the front end (or, if needed, the backend, too) use Debug. See https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Add to `wp-config.php`:

`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );`

and the debug.log file will be in wp-content. And/or, add this line

`define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);`

to dump them to the browser, too.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I force a revert to twentytwelve? I tried changing the themes folders name but then I just get a blank page on the front end

Comment: Renaming the active theme worked, however the front end did not revert to the twentytwelve theme - it just went blank - so I assumed the back end would not work either. It didnt occur to me to try loggin in wp-admin...

Comment: Rename the active theme and be sure there's a copy of twentytwelve to revert to. If you still get a white screen on the front end but can get into admin, the theme is still broken.